# How can we change status from Active to Inactive at play console

Tags: google-play, google-play-console

Currently, we have v5.2 in the market. In the play console, at the App bundle explorer section, it shows the Release status **Active** for v5.1

We need to change that **Active** status to **Inactive** because we are about to release v5.3 so uploaded a bundle for it. Done release process but it throws one error related to REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES for v5.1 which is already released in April 2022. After that, we released v5.2 in Sept 2022.

Can anyone help me to figure out how to change the release status Active to Inactive?

Answer (score 0):

Since your posting is already 6 months old, you have found a solution yourself already.

However, to whom it may concern, here is a solution that worked for me:

1.) Go to App bundle explorer and search for the noncompliant version codes. Click into the details page. See the "Releases" section and select "show detail". The Releases where the app-bundle (the one you would like to make inactive) is used are shown.

> 1 active
>
> 5 (v5.1)(Open Testing)

2.) click on the release in this section. You will be redirected  to the release.

3.) click "View Track" next to the "Release Summary" headline

4.) In the track's overview, choose "Create new Release" in the upper right corner

5.) Add a newer app bundle (one without the policy issue) to that release and check that the old app-bundle version code is listed below the "Deactivated app bundles" headline. Click "Next" in the lower right corner of the page

6.) Now, here comes the point where I got stuck all the times: On the subsequent page, the "save" button in the lower right corner might be disabled (grey). And on the top of the page there are boxes with a red (!)-sign and a text, stating that your appp with the old version code (e.g. 5) is not compliant due to the REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES policy violation.

The trick is to choose click "Dismiss" button in this message box. After that, the "save" button will be enabled and you can store the new release

7.) Select the "Publishing Overview" from the menu-bar. You will see pending changes for review. Click to send to review.

8.) Now, if this was the only release where your old app bundle was in use, then your old app-bundle will be marked as "inactive". If you had it in multiple releases, repeat all the steps for the remaining releases which make use of your old app-bundle